# A comment list Using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, comments

I would like to know create this sort of comment list with WPF using using input from the user. He will input the username and a comment. Then he will press submit. There will also be a time stamp on every comment submitted. Then the system will have a limit of 5 comments once a different user inputs the 6th comment the first one will be deleted and then the 2nd comment submitted will become the first and so on until the users stop submitting.

Sadly I am completely stumped and just can not figure out how to even start it, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for the 5 coment limit i would use `list.Add(comment); if(list.Count>5) {list.RemoveAt(1);}` so there will always be max 5 comments and the first one will be deleted (not sure if RemoveAt should be 0 or 1 you need to try it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally go with something around this way:

**ViewModel layer**

- You will need to create a UserComment class containing the following properies
  UserName,Comment,TimeStamp
- Another class which acts as the ViewModel of your UserCommentsView containing a property UserComments which returns an
  ObserableCollection of UserComment type.
- A ViewModel.AddUserCommentCommand property which adds a comment to
  UserComments - but before it checks the count of items in
  UserComments and removes the first/last (depending on your design)
  before adding a new comment.

**View layer**

- A listview with the above ViewModel as its context + items source
  being ViewModel.UserComments.
- A Button with its command bound to ViewModel.AddUserCommentCommand.

Have a look at  [Basic MVVM Listbox Binding in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806587/Basic-MVVM-Listbox-Binding-in-WPF) for MVVM binding.

and if you prefer code-behind: [ListView, data binding and ItemTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)